# Picasso Method does not override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android, picasso

I searched here and found nothing about this particular issue.

I want to implement Picasso in my app. But I can't override the methods onBitmapLoaded, onBitmapFailed and onPrepareLoad.

The error message is: "Method does not override method from its superclass".

Actually, these methods are not implemented em Picasso.java. But I need to use this methods. There is any alternative?

My code follows below:

```
            Picasso.with(this)
                .load(intent.getStringExtra("image_url"))
                .into(new Target()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStop() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroy() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Object resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setRequest(Request request) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public Request getRequest() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
                    {
                        showNotification(intent, bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image download failed");
                        RichPushService.this.stopSelf();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
                    {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The error is not due the 3 methods that you speak of.. It's because of the other random methods like `onStart`, `onStop` and so on which you've defined

Comment: Yeah, Activity's and Glide's overriden methods

Answer (score 1):

```
     Picasso.with(this)
    .load(pictureUrl)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            // not being called the first time
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
       });


                @Override
                public void onStart() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStop() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroy() {

                }

 Glide.with(yourApplicationContext))
.load(youUrl)
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {

                @Override
                public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Object resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder) {

                }

                @Override
                public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                }

                @Override
                public void setRequest(Request request) {

                }

                @Override
                public Request getRequest() {
                    return null;
                }
   };
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be an answer? You've just copied the code provided in the question and pasted it!

Comment: You have put the semi colon and braces incorrectly, which is why the error is shown. The overriden methods are of Activity class. Since you have put the semicolon and braves at the wrong positions, the methods are like overrding picasso which is utter nonsense

Comment: Nope that's not the problem.. Apart from a few those methods do not override the Activity class either

Comment: I have updated the answer. Your code has overriden methods of 3 interfaces: Avtivity, Picasso, Glide. I hadn't observed Glide at first. Now it's updated

Comment: Yeah true. But just because those methods exist in the source provided by him doesn't mean that he needs to implement them all. If you read the question his only motive is to implement the methods provided by Picasso so suggesting that he add the activity and Glide (which is a replacement for Picasso) is not really helpful

Comment: He doesn't even know whats onStart and onDestroy. Maybe he wants them. Maybe not. Yeah, mostly he doesn't have to use glide here

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Target's [source code](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Target.java)

There are only 3 methods that this interface implements so your code should look like

```
Picasso.with(this)
       .load(intent.getStringExtra("image_url"))
       .into(new Target()
            {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
                {
                    showNotification(intent, bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image download failed");
                    RichPushService.this.stopSelf();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
                {
                }
            }
```

Remove the other unnecessary methods defined.